# problem with jQuery.form plugin on second use

Tags: jquery, playframework, jquery-tabs, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm trying to use the [jQuery form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) plugin for the first time, inside a jQuery-ui tab. I'm able to load the form into the tab and submit the form. The request goes through successfully and the data **is added** to the database as planned. As it redirects to a clean version of the form the HTML gets put in the tab again, but I get a javascript error: `$ is not defined` referencing the line where jQuery is first used on the form page.

I'm assuming there's some sort of magic I haven't discovered yet. If it worked the first time, it should work the second time, shouldn't it?

---

Here's what I'm doing right now:

My form

```html
<div id="new-shift" class="${type.name}">

    <h2 id="crudBlankTitle">&{'crud.blank.title', type.modelName}</h2>

    <div class="objectForm">
    #{form action:@create(), id: 'new-shift-form', enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
        #{crud.form /}
        <p class="crudButtons">
            <input type="submit" name="_save" value="&{'crud.save', type.modelName}" />
            <input type="submit" name="_saveAndAddAnother" value="&{'crud.saveAndAddAnother', type.modelName}" />
        </p>
    #{/form}
    </div>

</div>
```

which is loaded into a jQuery-ui tabs element via ajax

```html
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li>#{a @Shifts.blank()}<span>New Shift</span>#{/a}</li>
    <!-- above line renders as 
    <li><a href="/shifts/new"><span>New Shift</span></a></li>
    -->
</ul>
</div>
```

and once it's loaded the Form plugin is applied

```js
<script>
$(function() {
        var tabs = $("#tabs");
        tabs.tabs({
                load: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#new-shift-form').ajaxForm({
                        target: '#new-shift'
                    });
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

---

**Update**: I've now tried this using `ajaxSubmit` as well, but the result is the same. "$ is not defined" when it loads the second time. Using `live` instead of applying the form plugin on load didn't help either. I'm really at a loss for what to try next.

```
$('#new-shift-form').live("submit", function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#new-shift',
        clearForm: true,
        replaceTarget: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Likely the page you are trying to get the response from contains an element with the same ID, creating duplicate IDs and messing up the submit.

Comment: Went through the rendered markup, but no duplicate ids. Of course, the id's from the second time the form is loaded match the ids from the first time, but I would think the first one would have to be removed before the second one is added.